# Azure transfer website location (Bizspark account)

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, bizspark

I have an Azure bizspark account which is hosted in east us. I need to transfer the location of the hosting to Europe, is it possible?

I have no problem creating a new website and transfer the data, but it seems that under my account I can't create a website in another location.

Does someone know if it's possible?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just select "Create New Web Hosting Plan" that appears directly above the "Subscription: BizSpark" in that drop down box that is showing.  Then you can select the Region to deploy to.

Comment: Will it still be under Bizspark subscription?

Comment: Yes, it will be under that subscription.

Answer (score 0):

I have Bizspark and it's not hosted anywhere specifically, of all the services I can dictate where they go, so whilst I am in Europe I can pick US or Asia for hosting anything.  Not sure why you have a restriction but that is probably the question which can be an account inquiry to MS.

Comment: I've edited the question and added a screen shot of the options I get.

Comment: So if I click create new hosting plan, then below I can add wherever I like, East US is only a default as that is possibly where other services which would link to it are.  I have two defaults as everything I have is in Europe in one of two DC's.